# Selenium c# how to put text form variable into xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have problem with putting string from variable into xpath writting test in Selenium c#.

I am trying to check if url adress from variable is placed in iframe

If I'm trying:

```
Assert.True(Page.CheckIfElementIsDisplayOnPage(By.XPath("//div[@class='widget-content']//iframe[contains(@src,'http://www.google.pl')]")));
```

Everything is ok. I get info that:

```
Element "By.XPath: //div[@class='widget-content']//iframe[contains(@src,'http://www.google.pl')]" is displayed.
```

But if I am trying to put url adress from variable:

```
string URLAdress = "http://www.google.pl";
Assert.True(Page.CheckIfElementIsDisplayOnPage(By.XPath(String.Format("//div[@class='widget-content']//iframe[contains(@src, {0})]", URLAdress))));
```

I got the info that:

```
Element "By.XPath: //div[@class='widget-content']//iframe[contains(@src, http://www.google.pl)] is not displayed
```

My source code is:

```
<div class="widget-content" style="height: 360.4px;">
<div style="height: 360.4px;">`
<iframe src="http://www.google.pl"/>
```

Can anybody help me?
Is it problem that in second condition in information that element is not displayed my url adress is without apostrophe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing single quotes.

```
"//div[@class='widget-content']//iframe[contains(@src, '{0}')]"
```

Comment: Yeah, You are my hero today, Thanks!